# Enumeration isn't properly indented from left

Tags: margins, enumerate

I have such a code:

```
%Start a document
\begin{document}
%Make nice title
\maketitle
\section{Zadání úlohy}
\subsection{Úkoly}
%Enumeration with custom labels
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic{*}:]
  \item Změřte proud tekoucí jednofázovou zátěží následujícími přístroji/senzory:
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{($A_\arabic{*}$)} ]
    \item ručním multimetrem s interním bočníkem
    \item pomocí externího bočníku Agilent 34330A a milivoltmetru Agilent
    \item proudovým transformátorem
    \item klešťovým ampérmetrem – wattmetrem
    \item pomocí proudových kleští a osciloskopu
   \end{enumerate} 
   Ve všech případech \textbf{určete a zdůvodněte}, jakou hodnotu proudu přístroje měří v případě harmonického průběhu proudu, neharmonického průběhu proudu a za přítomnosti stejnosměrné složky.\par
   Ve všech případech \textbf{určete} odpor přístroje/sestavy z pohledu vstupních svorek.
   Z přiložených údajů stanovte nejistotu měření proudu danou sestavou (mimo měření dle bodu e).
  \item Pomocí analyzátoru výkonu Tektronix PA1000 změřte příkon 1 fázové zátěže ve 3 fázové síti 3 x 40/70 V. V režimu „GRAPH“ zobrazte současně průběh napětí, proudu a výkonu.
  \item Ověřte funkci třífázového elektronického elektroměru a porovnejte údaje elektroměru s údaji naměřenými ostatními měřicími přístroji.
\end{enumerate}
```

I intentionally copied it all because I'm not sure what's wrong. What I expected to get is this:

[image: image description]

But what I got is this:

[image: image description]

Without custom labels, it behaves normally:

[image: image description]

What should I do? What did I do wrong when defining custom labels?

Comment: Put `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble and use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic{*}:,leftmargin=*]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `leftmargin=*`. I have also fixed some other glitches, mainly the proper usage of `\SI` for units, but also ties after one letter prepositions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\addto\extrasczech{\shorthandoff{-}}

\begin{document}

\section{Zadání úlohy}
\subsection{Úkoly}

%Enumeration with custom labels
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic{*}:,leftmargin=*]

\item Změřte proud tekoucí jednofázovou zátěží následujícími přístroji/senzory:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{($A_\arabic{*}$)},leftmargin=*]

  \item ručním multimetrem s interním bočníkem
  \item pomocí externího bočníku Agilent \SI{34330}{A} a milivoltmetru Agilent
  \item proudovým transformátorem
  \item klešťovým ampérmetrem – wattmetrem
  \item pomocí proudových kleští a osciloskopu

  \end{enumerate} 

Ve všech případech \textbf{určete a zdůvodněte}, jakou hodnotu proudu přístroje měří 
v~případě harmonického průběhu proudu, neharmonického průběhu proudu a za přítomnosti 
stejnosměrné složky.

Ve všech případech \textbf{určete} odpor přístroje/sestavy z pohledu vstupních svorek.
Z~přiložených údajů stanovte nejistotu měření proudu danou sestavou (mimo měření dle 
bodu~e).

\item Pomocí analyzátoru výkonu Tektronix PA1000 změřte příkon $1$~fázové zátěže ve 
$3$~fázové síti \SI[parse-numbers=false]{3\times 40/70}{V}. V~režimu „GRAPH“ 
zobrazte současně průběh napětí, proudu a výkonu.

\item Ověřte funkci třífázového elektronického elektroměru a porovnejte údaje 
elektroměru s~údaji naměřenými ostatními měřicími přístroji.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd probably change the inner `enumerate` specification to

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{A}$_\arabic{*}$),leftmargin=*]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @TomášZato I added a further suggestion

Comment: Can I ask what the SI unit's package does? I tried replacing hardcoded `$10M\Omega$` with `\SI{10000000}{Ohm}` but nothing spectacular happened.

Comment: @TomášZato `\SI{10}{\mega\ohm}`

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions. The second sets a left margin for the lists that will not change from one list to another (this may be important if you have many lists close to each other):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%Start a document
\begin{document}
%Make nice title
%\maketitle
\section{Zadání úlohy}
\subsection{Úkoly}
%Enumeration with custom labels
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic*:,align = left,labelindent = 0pt, labelsep*=0.5em, leftmargin=*,]
  %[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic*:,wide = 0pt, leftmargin=2em]widest ={\bfseries Úkol 1:},
  \item Změřte proud tekoucí jednofázovou zátěží následujícími přístroji/senzory:
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{($A_\arabic{*}$)}, wide=0pt ]
          \item ručním multimetrem s interním bočníkem
          \item pomocí externího bočníku Agilent 34330A a milivoltmetru Agilent
          \item proudovým transformátorem
          \item klešťovým ampérmetrem – wattmetrem
          \item pomocí proudových kleští a osciloskopu
        \end{enumerate}
        Ve všech případech \textbf{určete a zdůvodněte}, jakou hodnotu proudu přístroje měří v případě harmonického průběhu proudu, neharmonického průběhu proudu a za přítomnosti stejnosměrné složky.\par
        Ve všech případech \textbf{určete} odpor přístroje/sestavy z pohledu vstupních svorek.
        Z přiložených údajů stanovte nejistotu měření proudu danou sestavou (mimo měření dle bodu e).
  \item Pomocí analyzátoru výkonu Tektronix PA1000 změřte příkon 1 fázové zátěže ve 3 fázové síti 3 x 40/70 V. V režimu „GRAPH“ zobrazte současně průběh napětí, proudu a výkonu.
  \item Ověřte funkci třífázového elektronického elektroměru a porovnejte údaje elektroměru s údaji naměřenými ostatními měřicími přístroji.
\end{enumerate}
\vskip1cm
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Úkol \arabic*:,leftmargin=4em]
  \item Změřte proud tekoucí jednofázovou zátěží následujícími přístroji/senzory:
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{($A_\arabic{*}$)}, wide=0pt]
          \item ručním multimetrem s interním bočníkem
          \item pomocí externího bočníku Agilent 34330A a milivoltmetru Agilent
          \item proudovým transformátorem
          \item klešťovým ampérmetrem – wattmetrem
          \item pomocí proudových kleští a osciloskopu
        \end{enumerate}
        Ve všech případech \textbf{určete a zdůvodněte}, jakou hodnotu proudu přístroje měří v případě harmonického průběhu proudu, neharmonického průběhu proudu a za přítomnosti stejnosměrné složky.\par
        Ve všech případech \textbf{určete} odpor přístroje/sestavy z pohledu vstupních svorek.
        Z přiložených údajů stanovte nejistotu měření proudu danou sestavou (mimo měření dle bodu e).
  \item Pomocí analyzátoru výkonu Tektronix PA1000 změřte příkon 1 fázové zátěže ve 3 fázové síti 3 x 40/70 V. V režimu „GRAPH“ zobrazte současně průběh napětí, proudu a výkonu.
  \item Ověřte funkci třífázového elektronického elektroměru a porovnejte údaje elektroměru s údaji naměřenými ostatními měřicími přístroji.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]